# Proving the existence of a finite surjective map $V \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^d$ where $V$ is an algebraic set of dimension $d$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, and $V$ an algebraic set of dimension $d$. In the notes I am reading it states that there exists a finite surjective map from $V$ to $\mathbb{A}^d$, and proves the theorem. However, the proof relies on the fact that $V$ is irreducible.

I was wondering does this theorem holds even when $V$ is not irreducible? If so, how can I deduce the result from the irreducible case?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I assume for you, an algebraic set means an `affine' algebraic set-otherwise what you say is not correct. The proof is essentially Noether Normalization Theorem and you can look it up in many (commutative) algebra book.

Comment: @Mohan Yes, I do mean affine here. The notes uses Noether Normalization Theorem as well, so I am aware of the theorem. But I am just having trouble figuring it out for when $V$ is not irreducible...

Comment: May be this will help (Noether normalization). If $A$ is a finitely generated algebra over a field $k$, then there exists $x_1,\ldots, x_n\in A$ such that the map from $R=k[X_1,\ldots, X_n]$, a polynomial ring in $n$ variables to $A$, given by $X_i\mapsto x_i$ is injective and the map is integral (and thus $A$ is finitely generated module over $R$).

Comment: @Mohan I think I should have asked the question little differently: So my main concern is then how to show that this $n$ is the dimension of the algebraic set. The proof in the notes works only when $V$ is irreducible, but still claims it for any (affine) algebraic set (I was also wondering if it was a possible typo or not...).

Comment: If  $A\subset B$ a finite extension (of reasonable rings), then $\dim A=\dim B$.

Comment: @Mohan Could you possibly give me how to do this as an answer by any chance? I've been trying but I am still not quite seeing this...

Comment: Let $A$ denote the coordinate ring of $V$ (possibly reducible). Noether normalization says, there exists $x_1,\ldots,x_d\in A$ such that $R=k[x_1,\ldots, x_d]\subset A$ is a polynomial ring and $A$ is integral (and thus finite) over $R$. Then $\dim R=\dim A=d$ and we get a map $V\to\mathbb{A}^d$ as you desire using the $x_i$s.